# Iteration through the items in a given list

Tags: python, iteration

I have a trouble with an excercise, the problem is as follows:

```
list = ["hello", "mind", 1, 5, "six", ["eight", "night"]]

for item in list :
    print(item)
```

and the result is:

```
hello
mind
1
5
six
['eight', 'night']
```

but I wish to display these elements like this:

```
h
e
l
l
o
m
i
n
d
s
i
x
eight
night
```

Can you help me with this please?

Comment: Where did the `1` and `5` go in the desired output?

Comment: What is the logic here? Can you *describe* how the list should generate that output, based on some rules?

Answer (score 1):

```
# Don't name a variable 'list', it'll clobber the builtin list
L = ["hello", "mind", 1, 5, "six", ["eight", "night"]]

for x in L:
  try:
    for y in x:
      print(y)
  except TypeError:
    print(x)
```